# Unable to read files from Azure File Share

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4

My application has a mass upload feature where a user in a spreadsheets provides a file path for example Client1/Creative Files/File1.jpg which is how these files will be stored in the Cloud File Share. The mass upload process will read files from the location and if found, will then copy to the blob storage and create an entry in the database. Initially, I had everything in the blob storage, so reading the files was pretty straightforward.

```
CloudBlobContainer container = this.GetCloudBlobContainer();
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filePath);
```

As I couldn't map to a network drive for the blob storage account, I created a new storage account and created a file service, so I could map to the share on windows for the users to upload the files straight from their machine. Now, I am having issues getting files out of this share as it always says file does not exist.

```
public CloudFileShare GetCloudFileShare()
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(settings.AzureDropBoxConnectionString);
        CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
        CloudFileShare filehare = fileClient.GetShareReference(settings.AzureDropboxFileShare);
        filehare.CreateIfNotExists();

        return filehare;
    }
public CloudFile GetFileFromCloudShare(string filePath)
    {
        CloudFileShare fileShare = this.GetCloudFileShare();
        var file = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetFileReference(filePath);

        return file;
    }
```

When I check for file.Exists(), it comes back with "False" though the file is out there.

The filePath is Client1/Creative Files/File1.jpg. I guess if I just upload File1.jpg to the Share without the folders, this could should work but adding subfolders is creating a problem. We need to organize the files and there could be a few nested folders based on the clients and how the user organizes them on their end, that is why we ask them to provide the path in the spreadsheet. What am I missing?

When I debug the application and check for file StorageUri, I see https://storageaccount.file.core.windows.net/sharename/Client%5CCreative%20Files%5CFile1.jpg

Upon copying this url on the browser, I do not see the file. Like I said, with a blob container, this same process was working just file but when I moved the files to a file share, I am not able to return a file.

Comment: How are you ensuring that the file is present in the share? Are you using some kind of tool to check the existence of file?

Comment: I have mapped to the azure file share from windows and have uploaded the file in the same structure as indicated in the spreadsheet i.e. Client1/Creative Files/File1.jpg. I can also verify by going to the Azure portal -> Storage Account -> File Service -> Share. So, the file exists but its not when I use the code above.

Comment: One more thing...So in your code, you're passing `filePath` as `Client1/Creative Files/File1.jpg`. Correct?

Comment: Thats correct. Upon debugging, It comes up as Client1\\Creative Files\\File1.jpg.

Comment: In the spreadsheet, I have the filepath as Client1/Creative Files/File1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I tried specifying both `Client1\\Creative Files\\File1.jpg` as well as `Client1/Creative Files/File1.jpg` and in both cases I got file.Exists() to true. Can you please reconfirm that the file indeed exists.
2. You simply can't take the file URL and paste it in the browser and expect to see the file show up in the browser. In Blob Storage, you can set a container's ACL to `Blob` or `Container` and then when you copy the blob's URL in a browser's address window the blob will be displayed there. File Share on the other hand are always `Private` and access to the files need to be authorized. One thing you could do is create a `Shared Access Signature (SAS)` on the file and then copy the SAS URL in the browser's address window and then you will be able to see the file.

   ```
       var cred = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
       var account = new CloudStorageAccount(cred, true);
       var client = account.CreateCloudFileClient();
       var fileShare = client.GetShareReference("temp");
       var rootDirectory = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
       var file1 = rootDirectory.GetFileReference("Client1\\Creative Files\\test.png");
       Console.WriteLine(file1.Exists());
       var file2 = rootDirectory.GetFileReference("Client1/Creative Files/test.png");
       Console.WriteLine(file2.Exists());

       //Create shared access signature on file with read permission valid for 1 hour.
       var sasToken = file2.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessFilePolicy()
       {
           Permissions = SharedAccessFilePermissions.Read,
           SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
       });
       var fileSasUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}", file2.Uri.AbsoluteUri, sasToken);
       Console.WriteLine(fileSasUrl);
   ```

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity. I did check my file path and on the portal, one of the folders said "Creative Proofs" but in my test file, I had it as Creative Files. I apologize, i just kept looking Creative Files as Creative Proofs. Its working for sure now once I fixed my filepath. Thanks for providing an alternate solution using the shared access signature and boosting my confidence that the code should work. This just happened to be an error from the user side. :)